# Android client with Endpoints Python

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm try to connect an Android client with an endpoint in Python.
I follow this example :
https://googledrive.com/host/0B19L0O2pMOKjVUJBV0tEb0psVlU/#1

The generation of client libraries with endpointscfg.py is fine but when I import jar lib into my Android application i can't access to my Blog objet.

I also tried the sample TicTacToe android client https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android with python endpoint but not work too.

Edit : I can access to my service object, it's just a IDE coloration error. But still can't communicate with my endpoint :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fix my problem, I just forgot to add hostname annotation on my python api.

Comment: How did you manage to generate the discovery doc? I cannot seem to find the Endpoints Command Line Tool that they state is bundled with the SDK. Perhaps I am using endpointscfg.py incorrectly?